# Как в js проверить наличие элемента в массиве?

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
var users = [{
      id: 12,
      name: Adam
   },{
      id: 14,
      name: Bob
   },{
      id: 16,
      name: Charlie
   },{
      id: 18,
      name: David
   }
]
```

Как в таком массиве проверить на наличие свойства id со значением 18

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на нативном js без сторонних библиотек то:

```
const users = [{
      id: 12,
      name: Adam
   },{
      id: 14,
      name: Bob
   },{
      id: 16,
      name: Charlie
   },{
      id: 18,
     name: David
  }
]
function findElement(id) {
    const user =  users.find( (el) => el.id === id );
    if (user) { 
        return user;
    } else {
        return "user not found";
    }
}

findElement(18);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp

```js
var users = [{
  id: 12,
  name: "Adam"
}, {
  id: 14,
  name: "Bob"
}, {
  id: 16,
  name: "Charlie"
}, {
  id: 18,
  name: "David"
}];

var found = users.some(item => item.id == 18);
console.log(found);
```

Comment: почему не используешь lodash? :)

Comment: `console.log(_(found))`